# how to map related tables with LinqToSql and Automapper

Tags: linq-to-sql, automapper

I'm playing with Linq2SQL and Automapper to build DAL of my app.

Mapping from DomainModel to LinqModel:

```
public DataRepository(string connectionString)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModel, LinqModel>()
      .ForMember(x => x.SubLinqModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SubDomainModel))
    repository = new Linq2SqlRepository<DbDataContext, TDomainModel, TLinqModel>(new DbDataClassesDataContext(connectionString));
    }
```

DomainModel code:

```
public class DomainModel 
{
    public DomainModel()
    {
        SubDomainModelProperty = new List<SubDomainModel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SubDomainModel> SubDomainModelProperty { get; set; }
}
```

So, we have one-to-many relation in Domain Model. The same I have in LinqModel - two linked one-to-many tables

When I try to run this, I've got an error:

```
Trying to map System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SubDomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0,      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] to System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[SubLinqModel,     Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null].
Using mapping configuration for LinqModel to DomainModel
Destination property: SubLinqModel
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
```

How can I achieve this? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As determined from your code, and the part in the exception message, `Destination property: SubLinqModel`, you have to create a map from SubLinqModel to SubDomainModel.